# Polyline disappears when orientation changes - Android - GMaps V2

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-location, android-maps-v2

My MapActivity records a polyline just fine however when I tip the screen on it's side and the orientation changes the polyline disappears?  What could be causing this?  Here is my code that is recording the polyline:

```
Location lastLocationloc;
private GoogleMap myMap;
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if (lastLocationloc == null) { 
         lastLocationloc = location;
     }
     LatLng lastLatLng = locationToLatLng(lastLocationloc);
     LatLng thisLatLng = locationToLatLng(location);
     //Log.e(TAG, "Last LatLng is :"+lastLatLng);
     //Log.e(TAG, "Last LatLng is :"+thisLatLng);
     myMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions().add(lastLatLng).add(thisLatLng).width(10).color(Color.RED));
     lastLocationloc = location;
}
```

How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to save your points and restore them later. One simple way is to use `onSaveInstanceState` which will keep your data across configuration changes and process being killed. Other options are files and DB. More info here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html